# Removing top rows for a pair of elements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have in database a table that pairs two objects `ids (A,B)` and for each pair it has one Flag `(Flag_1)`.

The ObjectA and ObjectB pair is the primary key.

Table Example:

```
Object_A | Object_B | Flag_1 
 809790     809144      1   
 814231     809144      1   
 809790     510127      1   
 809022     809144      1    
 809790     803745      1   
 801250     782873      1   
 809022     623154      1   
 809022     911310      1
 809022     573158      1
 909022     573158      1
```

What I want to do to set the `Flag 1 to 0` to some of this rows.

The first thing I need is to get all the Object A that have more than two pairs.

```
SELECT  OBJECT_A
FROM    table
GROUP BY OBJECT_A
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 2
```

Results on Example Table:

```
Object_A 
 809790  
 809022
```

The second Thing is that I have to get all the `Object B,` ordered by ID, that are paired with the same `OBJECT_A`

```
SELECT *
FROM    table as t1
WHERE   (OBJECT_A IN
                    (SELECT   OBJECT_A
                     FROM  table  AS t2
                     GROUP BY OBJECT_A
                     HAVING         (COUNT(*) > 2)))
ORDER BY OBJECT_A, OBJECT_B DESC
```

Results on Example Table:

```
Object_A | Object_B | Flag_1 
 809790     809144      1   
 809790     803745      1    
 809790     510127      1     
 809022     911310      1   
 809022     809144      1    
 809022     623154      1    
 809022     573158      1
```

Now here is the tricky part. What I want to do is remove the first two pairs `(for each Object A)` and set the `Flag_1` to `0` for all the remaining pairs `(of that Object A)`.

Desired Results on Example Table:

```
Object_A | Object_B | Flag_1 
 809790     809144      1   
 809790     803745      1   
 809790     510127      0   
 809022     911310      1  
 809022     809144      1   
 809022     623154      0  
 809022     573158      0
```

It's a bit complex, so I hope that I explained the problem well enough. I might end up giving up and doing it programmatically in `C#`, but I still want to know if I could do it directly in SQL server. Maybe creating temporary tables ? Don't know.

Comment: is this value missing from your example data: `809022 573158` as it's in the results?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed That. I added that later to show that there might be more than 3 rows on each pair, and I want to change the flag on each pair that over the first two.

Comment: Try creating a `row_number()` on your result set and update the values of `Flag_1` where the row_number > 2?

Comment: @NickyvV Didn't think about that. I can use "row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Object_A ORDER BY Object_B DESC) AS row" and then update every pair that has row > 2.

Comment: @Kesty have updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
update t1
set t1.Flag_1 = 0
from table1 t1
inner join 
      (select t2.Object_A, t2.Object_B, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Object_A ORDER BY Object_A, Object_B DESC) AS RowNo
       from table1 t2             
                ) t2 on t1.Object_B = t2.Object_B and t1.Object_A = t2.Object_A
where t2.RowNo > 2
```

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6810/3)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Object_A] int, [Object_B] int, [Flag_1] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Object_A], [Object_B], [Flag_1])
VALUES
    (809790, 809144, 1),
    (814231, 809144, 1),
    (809790, 510127, 1),
    (809022, 809144, 1),
    (809790, 803745, 1),
    (801250, 782873, 1),
    (809022, 623154, 1),
    (809022, 911310, 1),
    (809022, 573158, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
update t1
set t1.Flag_1 = 0
from table1 t1
inner join (SELECT t2.Object_A, t2.Object_B, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Object_A ORDER BY Object_A, Object_B DESC) AS RowNo
              FROM table1 t2              
            ) t2 on t1.Object_B = t2.Object_B and t1.Object_A = t2.Object_A
where t2.RowNo > 2

select * 
from table1
order by 1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6810/3/0)**:

```
| OBJECT_A | OBJECT_B | FLAG_1 |
|----------|----------|--------|
|   801250 |   782873 |      1 |
|   809022 |   573158 |      0 |
|   809022 |   623154 |      0 |
|   809022 |   809144 |      1 |
|   809022 |   911310 |      1 |
|   809790 |   510127 |      0 |
|   809790 |   803745 |      1 |
|   809790 |   809144 |      1 |
|   814231 |   809144 |      1 |
```

Comment: I think this is the right track, but there might be still some problems. I have 40k rows in my DB. If I do a group by OBJECT_A having count(*)>2 I get 4k results. With the ROW_NUMBER > 2 version I got 20k

Comment: @Kesty but the group by will merge the rows, so if the result has 4 rows, they will be rolled into 1. Where as the row number will be a  list of the repeated rows as they have a distinct row number.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right. I'm staring at this problem for too long, need a break :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was able to do the update but there was a problem with your answer in the update. Object b is not unique, as you can see that id 809144 is paired both with multiple ObjectA.  So your update would have updated every pair with the objectB in the select. You can see the error in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6810/1 whit a new field. What I have done is add an auto increment index on the table and made the update on the index instead of the ObjectB. Mabye there is a better option. Can we fix the answer, so I don't have to unaccept ?

Comment: This SqlFiddle has the auto increment field added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9113b/1 I've not edited your answer because maybe you have a better solution, without adding the auto increment.

Comment: will it work if you join on `t1.Object_B = t2.Object_B and t1.Object_A = t2.Object_A`like this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6810/3